# Allow www-data to execute a a script

Tags: shell-script, permissions

I am trying to execute a script that will read a file written by PHP. The  problem is that the script opens and some other files (C-ISAM file based database) and i have no clue what permisions to give at these files.. Should i add www-data to my group ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you just do

```
chgrp www-data yourfile
chmod g+rw yourfile
```

Comment: my files are already to a group which shouldnt change.

Comment: Does the server support ACLs? Do you have root access?

Comment: i have root access.I dont know what ACL is. I tried with sudoers file but it asks me for password for www-data when i try to use sudo.